# Using ToExpression within Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, contexts

I would like to use `ToExpression` (or `Symbol`) within `Manipulate`. Specifically, when running `Manipulate`, I want to build variables from strings, convert them to symbols (dynamic ones) and return values. But I guess I am missing something. Possibly very straight forward.

Here's an example:

```
a2 = 37; (*GLOBAL*)

Manipulate[
Module[{a1 = 1, a2 = 2, a3 = 3, a4 = 4}, 
Column[{text, var, ToExpression[text <> ToString@var],a1}]], {{text, 
"a"}, {"a", "b"}}, {var, 1, 2, 1, ControlType -> SetterBar}]
```

So I set a global `a2` (to visualize the effect), the rest is local and it returns:

[image: Manipulate 1][image: Manipulate 2]

If I change to `a2`, the **global** value is retrieved in the third line, i.e. 37, see the screenshot on the right.

So I think the contexts are confusing me. In order to solve my problem, here's what I tried then: I created a `Dynamic` `x`outside the `Manipulate` and well, consistently (to me), I can now use two different sliders to control the variables (both called `x`) within `Manipulate`, see here:

```
Column[{{Slider[Dynamic[x]], Dynamic[x]},
   Manipulate[
      Column[{
       Style["Within Manipulate", Bold], 
         x, Dynamic[x],ToExpression[x], "", 
       Style["Context", Bold], 
         Context[x], Head[x],"", 
       Style["Converting String", Bold], 
         ToExpression["x"], Dynamic@ToExpression["x"], 
         ToExpression["Dynamic[x]", InputForm, Hold], 
         ToExpression["FE`x"], ToExpression["Global`x"], 
         ToExpression["x", InputForm, Dynamic]}], 
   {{x, 2.5}, 2, 3}]}]
```

resulting in: (note: running command in Mathematica directly returns context FE`, whereas it returns FE`Global` using export)

[image: Manipulate]

So, my question is: is there an easy way within `Manipulate` to go from strings to symbols? (outside `Manipulate`, it works just as I expect it to)

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

To clarify: when I use a variable directly in `Manipualte`(such as `a1`) its (local) value is returned (i.e. `1`), if I use `ToExpression["a1"]` (i.e. from string) it retrieves the global value. And whats confusing: `ToExpression[a1]` yields local value.

So the question: how to retrieve the local value of a variable in `Manipulate` when given the "name" (string) of the variable.

Comment: @Nasser: I added an edit above, I hope this helps. The slider I use outside `Manipulate` is just to show that "some" of the `x` within `Manipulate` actually depend on that - which is not what I want. Further, I added `a2=37`as a Global var to visualize what is happening, i.e. where `ToExpression["a2"]` is referring to

Answer (score 2):

Actually we do not need Manipulate to look at this issue. Manipulate just confuses things a little. Lets just simplify things more and just use standard `Modules`

Lets make a global `a1` symbol with the value `-99`. Then create a `Module` with a local `a1` symbol of value 1 then display the value of `a1` from applying `ToExpression` to the string "a1".

We see the same issue. It displays `-99` (the global one) and not `1` (the local one) as expected.

```
a1 = -99;
Module[{a1 = 1, str},
 str = "a" <> ToString@1;
 Grid[{
   {"string for expression is ", str},
   {"ToExpression[a1] = ",   ToExpression[str]},
   {" my local a1 = ", a1}
   }, Alignment -> Left]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This shows that `ToExpression` works at the global level.

Replacing `Module` with `With` gives the same result

```
a1 = -99;
With[{a1 = 1},
 str = "a" <> ToString@1;
 Grid[{
   {"string for expression is ", str},
   {"ToExpression[a1] = ",   ToExpression[str]},
   {" my local a1 = ", a1}
   }, Alignment -> Left]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But using `Block` makes it finally use the local symbol

```
a1 = -99;
Block[{a1 = 1},
 str = "a" <> ToString@1;
 Grid[{
   {"string for expression is ", str},
   {"ToExpression[a1] = ",   ToExpression[str]},
   {" my local a1 = ", a1}
   }, Alignment -> Left]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So, what is the conclusion out of all this? Just do NOT use `ToExpression` ;)

Actually `ToExpression` is not even allowed in demos.  So I never used it myself. But from the above, you can just assume when it evaluates the expression, it is done in the global context (i.e. it removes any context currently attached to the symbol, leaving it by default in the global context) but an expert in the Mathematica language would know more about this. part. I do not claim to be one.

**update**
Actually, the context of these symbols are still Global, and I think that is why `ToExpression` does what it does. We can display the context of each symbol and see:

```
Clear[foo, a1, x];
a1 = -99;
foo[] := Module[{a1 = 1, x},
   str = "a" <> ToString@1;
   Grid[{
     {"string for expression is ", str},
     {"ToExpression[a1] = ",   ToExpression[str]},
     {" my local a1 = ", a1},
     {" context of  a1 = ", Context[a1]},
     {" context of  x = ", Context[x]}
     }, Alignment -> Left]
   ];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Probably the safest way to do what you want is to create explicitly your own `Context` as in `Begin["local`"]; ...... ;  End[];` as happens in packages. But this is beyond the scope of this.

Comment: Thanks for that answer and your effort, it certainly covers my problem at hand. It is a nice illustration of the difference `Module`vs. `Block` and scoping. But well, I do find it hard to believe that there is another function (apart from `ToExpression` and `Symbol`) to convert a string to a var in a local context